# Hash condition in where method Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue attempting to perform this call:

```
 animals = pet_animals.where(
    :healthy => true,
    :owned => false,
    :bought <= bought_date
  )
```

This line is causing errors. `:bought <= bought_date`
How can I perform this comparison?

Comment: The => symbols do not mean “greater than or equal to” in this context, they are just hash separators. If you want that comparison it’ll be another where call after that which will look like:  .where(‘bought <= ?’, bought_date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running one an up-to-date version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails then you can use in infinite range to describe the condition:

```
animals = pet_animals.where(
  healthy: true, owned: false, bought: (..bought_date)
)
```

For version for Ruby below Ruby 2.6 or prior Rails 6.0 you need to use the array syntax to describe such conditions:

```
animals = pet_animals.where(healthy: true, owned: false)
                     .where("bought <= ?", bought_date)
```

Btw I switched to the newer hash syntax because it is more common nowadays than the old hash rocket (`=>`) in cases like these.